# vim: открыть файл через контекстное меню

Tags: vim

Как сделать чтобы vim (не gvim) открывал файлы через контекстное меню в новых вкладках подобно sublime, не открывая новое окно для каждого открытого файла? Подобная запись для vim.desktop не работает:

```
Exec=vim -p --remote-tab-silent %F
Terminal=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«имя сервера» надо указать. чтобы было к чему подключаться (если экземпляра программы с таким именем ещё не было запущено, то текущий экземпляр будет считаться «сервером» с указанным именем).

---

запускаем редактирование файла `файл1` и присваиваем этому экземпляру «имя сервера» `имя1`:

```
$ vim --servername имя1 --remote-tab-silent файл1
```

смотрим список запущенных «серверов»:

```
$ vim --serverlist
имя1
```

подключить к тому же «серверу» ещё и `файл2`:

```
$ vim --servername имя1 --remote-tab-silent файл2
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо большое, конкретно для ярлыка получилось сделать подобным образом:
Exec=vim --servername vim --remote-tab-silent %f